# Autoload definition in ext_emconf.php for typo3 7.6

Tags: autoload, typo3-7.6.x

What are the different ways to write autoload function for an extension with no namespace in emconf.php for typo3 7.6??

Answer (score 2):

I just find a way do this on typo3 v7.
You had this follow line in your ext_emconf.php

```
'autoload' =>
   array(
        'classmap' =>
        array(
          'Classes', // standar directory
          'Resources/3rdParty/oauth/' // other lib 
        )
  )
```

Hope it will answer to you problem